# Service Worker force reload issue

Tags: service-worker, workbox

We have a page which uses client side rendering. We have a desktop App in which this page is shown. The cache strategy we are using is stale while revalidate.

The issue :

There is a refresh button in our app. When this button gets clicked, we want to use network first strategy for page rendering(all the images,assets) which are fetched using xhr calls should be fetched as per this strategy.

The problem arises as, when we fetch the basic html page from the server lets say hello.html as well as javascript files from the server , when these javascript files are used to render the page on the client side, it will still use the cached content.

Is there an easy way i can send a custom header for all the xhr calls for this page so that i can tell service worker to use network first strategy for all these requests.

I know i can do it for the page (hello.html) and tell service worker to use network first strategy for it but not how to do it for all the xhr calls made by this page.